# Making RecyclerView return a unique array in every view from SQLITE database

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

MyDB db = new MyDB(mContext);

ArrayList<String> images1=db.getCollection(1); // Returns 2 image URIs in an array
ArrayList<String> images2=db.getCollection(2); // 0 images
ArrayList<String> images3=db.getCollection(3); // 2 images
ArrayList<String> images4=db.getCollection(4); // 10 images
ArrayList<String> images5=db.getCollection(5); // 5 images
ArrayList<String> images6=db.getCollection(6); // 12 images

//Maximum 12 images per collection
```

I've tried:

```
for(int i=0;i<images1.size();i++){

String path1=images1.get(i);
holder.img1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path1));

}

for(int j=0;j<images2.size();j++){

String path2=images2.get(i);
holder.img2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path2));

}

for(int k=0;k<images3.size();k++){

String path3=images3.get(i);
holder.img3.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path3));

}

//Sets each view the same, of course.
```

How do I get recyclerview to assign each view to a different collection of 12 images(or less)?

Since the collection can grow in size, is there another way to get unique images(upto 12) into each view of RecyclerView?

Comment: can you add your list_item.xml as well or whatever you called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A position element is returned in bindViewHolder where you can use that..1st you have to take 12 ImageViews and assign them in a array of imageViews. let it take `imgs[]`

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

MyDB db = new MyDB(mContext);

ArrayList<String> images1=db.getCollection(position);
for(int i=0;i<images1.size();i++){
    String path1=images1.get(i);
    holder.imgs[i].setImageURI(Uri.parse(path1));

}
@override
int getItemCount(){
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: Will I have to implement ArrayAdapter for this?

Comment: A simple class extending `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition in your recycler view adapter. And set colour accordingly.

Something like this

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {

       //
       when(noteModel.noteColor){
                1 ->
                    holder.relativeBack.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light))
                2 ->
                    holder.relativeBack.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light))

       }
    }
```

You can find the sample code in this [GitHub project file](https://github.com/sreeharikv112/NoteApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/noteapp/uicomponents/activities/landing/NoteAdapter.kt)

Full source code over [here](https://github.com/sreeharikv112/NoteApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/noteapp/uicomponents/activities/landing)